# How to Install CakePHP 3 in subdirectory

Tags: cakephp, subdirectory, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

How do I install CakePHP 3 in a subdirectory?  So far, I've only found that I should set my App.base variable in `config/app.php` file, but I've tried every path I can think of, but only get 500 error.

**Overview of how it should end up:**

User goes to `www.example.com` and gets my 'app1' CakePHP 3 application.  User goes to `www.example.com/app2` and gets my 'app2' application (standard PHP for now, but eventually another Cake app).

**Here's my general file structure:**

```
/
.htaccess *see contents below
application1/
    bin/
    config/
    logs/
    plugins/
    src/
    ...etc
application2/
    index.php - just does an: echo 'APP2!';
```

**I've tried changing my App.base to each of these:**

```
'App' => [
    'base' => '/application1',
    //'base' => '/example.com/application1', 
    //'base' => '/vhosts/example.com/application1', 
    //'base' => '/www/vhosts/example.com/application1', 
    //'base' => '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/application1',
```

**My .htacess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^application2/?$ /application2/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing?  Are there other steps I need to take?  Is what I've done so far incorrect?

Comment: Seeing as it's your app1 that's being relocated, why not rewrite that instead of app2 that's actually in the correct place?

Comment: @Deanna not sure what you mean.  They're both in the "correct" place.

Comment: Yes, but you're trying to make the contents of `/app1/` appear in `/` (without `app1/` showing)? Or is your question badly phrased? :)

Comment: It very well could be badly phrased.  I want two apps.  One in the `/application1` directory, and the other in the `/application2` directory.  Seems a lot cleaner than having one in the root, and another Cake project within the first Cake project.  I assumed I would handle by sending the root directory to one of them (either), and using htaccess to point to the other.

Comment: Well, the "other" is already in the place where it's going to be accessed,no need for a redirect. App1, you want to appear in the root, so use mod rewrite to handle App1, rather than just a `include() `.

Comment: I expect the `include()' is what's confusing it as the script location and all paths around it are no longer what it expects.

Comment: I've removed the index.php file with require, but lost as to what to do next.  Are you suggesting I just add another RewriteRule to handle "everything else"?

Comment: Have you checked your logs to see what exactly the 500 error is caused by? What I can see from here is an invalid rewrite rule pattern, the stray closing parenthese would cause Apache to trigger a 500.

Comment: this kind of thing is a lot easier if you make application1/webroot the document root, and put application2/webroot into it. Note that you can put your code wherever you want and use symlinks to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

In www.example.com/app2

Modify yur .htaccess to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /application2/
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```